# Switch-case / OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Вопрос наверное элементарный, но почему-то не работает код в switch-case с OnClickListener имплементированным в активность.

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "this is toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "this is toast2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast2.show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Хотя, если несколько изменить код: убрать имплементацию и менять видимость кнопок в методах, определенных через xml в "onClick", все работает.
Пропустил что-то со слушателем или ошибка в swicth-case?

Comment: Что делать когда кто-то [ответил на ваш вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли навесить слушатели после инициализации, типа

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: О, точно, спасибо)